# Can't Reset Input Value Based on Select Field When Form Split into Child Components

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm showing and hiding a FormControl based on another FormControl in the same FormGroup, which works using the method below, but when I try to reset the input being hidden so on submit it's value is not sent I get the error below.

**Component Method**

```
public hasOtherFundingSource(index: number) {
  const formGroup = this.overviewFunds.at(index);
  const source = formGroup.get('source').value;

  if (source !== 'other') {
    formGroup.get('other_source_desc').reset(); // Throws error
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
ExampleComponent.html:12 ERROR Error: 
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: 
Expression has changed after it was checked. 
Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
```

With some help form @yurzui I created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MTpsszgEykK8BTaXh1UP?p=preview) that shows the error.  Just change `other` to `another` in the select field and watch the console log out the error.  The error seems to be related to splitting the FormGroup into sub-components to reduce the size and logic in each class.

If you look at the first [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1VE7JfEZwpxmFQY8dmOD?p=preview) that was created the error doesn't occur when the form is encapsulated in the app-component.

Comment: Plunker would be helpful

Comment: I can set that up, but the meat of the question is change detection when the select value = 'other' how do I reset the input that's being show/hidden since it can't be done in the method provided, and valueChange isn't specific enough.

Comment: Here is fixed plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/XgV8LV8ZTFvP9z1euMnA?p=preview (i added `[formGroupName]="i"`). How can we reproduce your error?

Comment: Hi @yurzui sorry I had to update the plunker to get the error to occur - https://plnkr.co/edit/MTpsszgEykK8BTaXh1UP?p=preview.  The form locally is separated into child components so the overview and character FormGroup are components.  The error doesn't occur when the entire form is within a single component, but splitting the form up into small more digestable child components causes the error.

Comment: I apologize for the delay, I slept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid any side effect within functions that will be executed on every view checking

```
<div *ngIf="hasOtherFundingSource(i)">
```

`hasOtherFundingSource` function will be executed twice in dev mode on every application tick.

There is `NgControlStatus` directive that checks validation status.

On the first check your form is valid

[image]

After that you're calling `formGroup.get('other_source_desc').reset();` and status becames `invalid`

[image]

Then angular is running `view.checkNoChanges()` and you get `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`

So according to https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#no-visible-side-effects

### No visible side effects

**A template expression should not change any application state other than the value of the target property.**

> This rule is essential to Angular's "unidirectional data flow" policy.
>   You should never worry that reading a component value might change
>   some other displayed value. The view should be stable throughout a
>   single rendering pass.

To solve your problem i did the following:

1) Added `ngModelChange` event to `select` control

```
<select formControlName="source" (ngModelChange)="sourceChanged($event, i)">
```

2) Move side effect from `hasOtherFundingSource` to sourceChanged function

```
sourceChanged(value: string, index: number) {
  if (value !== 'other') {
      const formGroup = this.overviewFunds.at(index);
      formGroup.get('other_source_desc').reset();
  }
}
```

**[Modified Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vNLu8jZ7YIpJ0hbZFbmB?p=preview)**

Comment: Wow, that is a great answer.  Thanks so much for the explanation and screenshots that really helps it stick :)

Comment: I think the only other thing I'm still a bit confused on it is why it works when contained all in one component like the second plunker in the question. Just think of it as a side effect?

Comment: It depends on checking order. When you create child component it will be checked after parent

Comment: Sorry @yurzui found another issue, but I can't seem to replicate it in the plunker.  After I change 'other' to 'another' clearing the input, then show the input, then hide it again I get this error.  `ERROR ObjectUnsubscribedError {originalStack: "Error: object unsubscribed↵    at ObjectUnsubscrib…(http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:23718:14)",...`.  I've been trying to figure out for the last couple hours after finding it, but I'm not getting anywhere.  Are you able to point me in the right direction?  I'm not unsubscribing from anything and there is no visual difference between the code.

Comment: Which version angular are you using?

Comment: The latest v4.1.  I made sure I had the same version as the plunker so updated from v4.0.3 after I noticed the issue hoping that might be the fix.  Sorry this time I had to sleep :)

Comment: This error seems to be related to using `*ngIf`. It occurs when the input has been removed from the DOM by `*ngIf` then replaced, but only throws when the input value has been deleted (manually or by reset) after being replaced.  If I use `[hidden]` instead the error doesn't occur.  Seems like the reference to the `FormControl` has been lost (hence the unsubscribe in the error)? It's weird that the value has to be removed (manually or by reset) for the error to throw after being replaced.  Also, don't understand why it doesn't occur in the plunker?